# Click event on element tr doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, click, tr

I've got this javascript code and some tr elements inside a table, but the click event simply doesn't work on this element, I've already tried on other elements, such as div, and it worked. Does anybody know why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').bind('click',function(){
    alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: :As of jQuery 1.7, the **.on()** method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Not that it changes anything if it is being called on one element and not the other..

Comment: Works as is for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VRxtQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, try an alternative to click or on methods. Have a look to these codes :

```
// With click
$(function() {
    $('tr').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});

// With on
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'tr', function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Check also if your tr is visible like this :

```
$(function() {
    if($('tr').is(':visible')) {
        alert('visible');
    }
});
```